# Wavesurfer.js -Is there any way to know, which frame(start or end) of region is getting updated on dragging?

Tags: wavesurfer.js

I have case in which I need to updated video frame when we drag region from waveform. I know that even "region-updated" get trigger when we move/drag region, and get Region object in callback. I am able to handle the case when we drag the whole region. But, when user drag only start or end of region, Do we get any information on whether start or end is being drag of region?

Answer (score 0):

When region is being updated "region-updated" even is triggered with the region details. This is how you can access it.

```
wavesurfer.on('region-updated', function(region){

region.start;
region.end;

})
```

Hope this helps!